# How should I go about rendering text in Metal?

Tags: swift, text, rendering, metal

I only need to render 2 dimensional text, but the examples (Text Rendering by MetalByExample.com) I found are in Objective-C, very messy, and probably have a lot of muck (code or steps that aren't necessary for full functionality). How should I go about rendering simple text in Metal? This is trivial in SwiftUI, but how do I do it in Metal? I know this question is kind of vague but there's very little useful resources on how to render simple text in Metal. How could I render a simple hello world text, given this starting code?

```
import Cocoa
import MetalKit
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private let Device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
    private var CommandQue: MTLCommandQueue!, Pipeline: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    private var View: MTKView {
        return view as! MTKView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        View.delegate = self
        View.device = Device
        CommandQue = Device.makeCommandQueue()
        let PipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        let Library = Device.makeDefaultLibrary()!
        PipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = Library.makeFunction(name: "V")
        PipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = Library.makeFunction(name: "T")
        Pipeline = try? Device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: PipelineDescriptor)
    }
}
extension ViewController: MTKViewDelegate {
    func mtkView(_ _: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange Size: CGSize) {
        View.draw()
    }
    func draw(in _: MTKView) {
        let CommandBuffer = CommandQue.makeCommandBuffer()!, CommandEncoder = CommandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: View.currentRenderPassDescriptor!)!
        CommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(Pipeline!)
        
        // Render
        
        CommandEncoder.endEncoding()
        CommandBuffer.present(View.currentDrawable!)
        CommandBuffer.commit()
    }
}
```

Basically how could I replicate this simple SwiftUI in Metal? I'm not asking for a 'code this for me' but I would like some pointers on where to start?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Core Image's [`CITextImageGenerator`](https://cifilter.io/CITextImageGenerator/) for that. (There is also `CIAttributedTextImageGenerator` for attributed text.)

Just create a `CIImage` containing the text and use a `CIContext` to render the text into a `MTLTexture` (or into the view directly):

```
// Render
let textImage = CIFilter(name: "CITextImageGenerator", parameters: [
    "inputText": "Hello World!",
    "inputFontName": "HelveticaNeue",
    "inputFontSize": 40,
    "inputScaleFactor": 2.0
]).outputImage!

// Note: create the CIContext once and re-use it
self.ciContext.render(textImage, to: View.currentDrawable!, commandBuffer: CommandBuffer, bounds: textImage.extent colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())
```

As of macOS 10.15 you can also `import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins` and use the new protocol-based Core Image interface:

```
let textImageGenerator = CIFilter.textImageGenerator()
textImageGenerator.text = "Hello World!"
// ...
let textImage = textImageGenerator.outputImage!
```

If you want to change the color of the text, you can either use the `CIAttributedTextImageGenerator` with an attributed string or use more Core Image filters and blending techniques to colorize the text image before rendering it into the view.

Comment: What does the `self` refer to in this case?

Comment: The view controller, for instance. Something that can hold a reference to the `CIContext` you use for rendering the text into the view. The context itself you can just create on `init` with `self.ciContext = CIContext()`.

Comment: I see, but `render` isn't accepting `View.currentDrawable!` because it has to be an `MTLTexture` but if I do `View.currentDrawable!.texture` it doesn't work because it's frame buffer only

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot. You can just set `View.framebufferOnly = false` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: How do I change the color, and additionally is there a way to do it w/o all the string literals?

Comment: Also it would be nice to be able to do it with a `drawIndexPrimitives` call

Comment: I edit the answer to address some of your recent questions. Why and how would you want to draw text with `drawIndexPrimitives`? If you want to add text onto your rendering primitives, you need to create a texture that contains the text and map that on your geometry.

Comment: The capabilities of text generator filter are very limited, one can do that using CGContext and CoreText as well. Does textImageGenerator uses GPU or CPU to generate text?

Answer (score 0):

I spent two days sourcing simplest implementation so the best for me is to use Alloy [pod](https://github.com/s1ddok/Alloy) and converting UILabel to cgImage

```
func createImage() -> UIImage {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
                CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height), true, 1)
            self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image!
        }
```

then to mtltexture

```
context = try! MTLContext(device: Device.shared.device)

let texture = try! context.texture(from: cgImage!,
                                            srgb: false,
                                           usage: [.shaderRead, .shaderWrite])
```